# Postgres CREATE DATABASE already has data and tables

Tags: postgresql

When I do a: `DROP DATABASE` mydb; and subsequently: `CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH OWNER user;` the new `mydb` database is created with all the tables and data that I had in the database I just dropped. What am I be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably created some tables (with data) in the database `template1`.

Connect to that database (e.g.: `psql postgres template1`) and drop everything you don't need there.

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be falling afoul of one of the restrictions on the [command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html):

1. It can only be executed by the database owner.
2. It cannot be executed while you or anyone else are connected to the target database.
3. It cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

Comment: The problem is not that he/she can **not** create the database - the database *is* created. The problem is that the (newly) created database contains stuff that shouldn't be in there.

Comment: Depending on how they're doing the drop/create (psql/pgAdmin/script), an unnoticed failure to drop will mean that the data never got removed and the subsequent create will fail but the data will still be there. It looks like you correctly identified the problem though.